# npm 5.8.0: ERR! when using ng new

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

I'm having this error every time I will create new angular project. Not sure where this belong (npm or angular-cli)

[image]

`node -v v8.11.1`

`npm -v 5.8.0`

`ng -v 6.0.0`

Everything before are good. This just happen, including serving other projects throws an error (but not like this)

Answer (score 0):

It's an issue in updated version of `npm`

> Downgrade to  5.6.0 and it should work

```
npm install -g npm@5.6.0
```

Find the open issue on [Github](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/19989)

[image]